# How to get smart contract balance on Archway?

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

```
let balance = BankQuery::Balance { denom, address };
```

This thing returns **BankQuery** but I need a **String** or **u128** value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to get the balance, you need to use the `querier` available within `deps`. Afterward, you can convert the value to `u128`. The following should work:

```rust
pub fn get_balance(
    deps: &DepsMut,
    env: Env,
) -> Result<u128, StdError> {
    let denom = "<add-denom>";
    let address = "<add-address>";
    let balance_query = BankQuery::Balance { denom, address };
    let balance_response: BalanceResponse = deps.querier.query(&balance_query.into())?;
    let balance_u128 = balance_response.amount.amount.u128();
    Ok(balance_u128)
}
```